# Microsoft Bot Framework (WebChat) - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: botframework

From "Test in Web Chat" window in Azure Dashboard, I entered "hello" which is correctly received in my backend, but I'm still figuring out how to reply.

*Note: WORDS IN CAPS means variable.*

```
curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLI-ENT-ID&client_secret=SECRET&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default" -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

Response: {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"ext_expires_in":0,"access_token":"VERY_LONG_STRING"}

curl -d '{"type":"message","from":{"id":"mybot@SOME_ID","name":"mybot"},"conversation":{"id":"CONVERSATION_ID"},"recipient":{"id":"RECIPIENT_ID","name":"You"},"locale":"en","text":"hello too","replyToId":"CONVERSATION_ID|0000008"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer VERY_LONG_STRING" -X POST https://api.botframework.com/v3/conversations/CONVERSATION_ID/activities/CONVERSATION_ID%7C0000008

Response: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Request from my app (also same error):

```
POST /v3/conversations/CONVERSATION_ID/activities/CONVERSATION_ID%7C0000008 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer VERY_LONG_STRING
User-Agent: Java-SDK
Content-Length: 273
Host: api.botframework.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

{"type":"message","from":{"id":"mybot@SOME_ID","name":"mybot"},"conversation":{"id":"CONVERSATION_ID"},"recipient":{"id":"RECIPIENT_ID","name":"You"},"locale":"en","text":"hello too","replyToId":"CONVERSATION_ID|0000008"}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: What does your actual bot code look like? 500 generally mean the problem is within the bot code.

Comment: What documentation are you using to assist in formulating the reply?  Specifically, why are you posting a message to https://api.botframework.com ?  The url changes based on channel, but I am not aware of a channel that uses api.botframework.com.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comment from Eric Dahlvang, I figure it out.

By default, `ApiClient` generated from swagger will have its `basePath` hardcoded to `https://api.botframework.com`.

Before replying, take the `serviceUrl` from incoming `Activity` and use it to change the `basePath`.